# compare of domains $D_a$ and $D_c$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a smooth function on $[-1,1]$, such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in(-1,1)$,$f(-1)=f(1)=0$. consider $\gamma\subset\Bbb{R}^2$ the graph of the $f(x)$. Let $T_a$ the symmetry with respect to axis $x$ and $T_c$ the central symmetry with respect to origin. Now consider two domains $D_a$:bounded by the curves $\gamma$ and $T_a(\gamma)$, and $D_c$: bounded by the curves $\gamma$ and $T_c(\gamma)$. How is compare of domains $D_a$ and $D_c$? ($D_a\subset D_c$ or $D_c\subset D_a$)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the two domains are not comparable: consider $f(x)=(x+1)(1-x)^2$ for instance.

If $f$ is even, then $D_a=D_c$.

Comment: Or: since the domains have equal area, containment is only possible as equality.